# How to GRANT CREATE TABLE TO ROLE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to give a role the permission of create a table in a database :

```
CREATE LOGIN log1 WITH PASSWORD = '123'
GO

CREATE USER user1 FOR LOGIN log1
GO

CREATE ROLE [roleTEST]
GO

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [roleTEST]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Groupe TO [roleTEST]
GO

ALTER ROLE [roleTEST] ADD MEMBER [user1]
GO
```

I login with `USER1`, when I select something from `dbo.groupe` table, I got the rows correctly, but when I tried to `CREATE` a table, I got an error like :

> Msg 2797, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 1
>   Le schéma par défaut n'existe pas

It means that grant select work but grant create table doesn't, so how can I grant a create table to a role, and not to a special user?

Comment: What schema will the table go in?  Who will own that schema?

Comment: i didn't understand :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you would need one more:

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::DBO TO [ROLETEST]
```

Please find more details [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd283095(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: You might as well grant CONTROL to the role if grant it ALTER on the DBO schema,  Ownership chains will enable role members to run arbitrary DML on  any dbo-owned table.  Better to create a new schema and make that role the owner of the schema.